# Rust lifetime String to str in Vec loop

Tags: rust, lifetime

I just started to learn Rust and I'm trying to compare two versions of type `String`. As the Version::from function only accepts `&str`, I'm trying to convert, but then I get the error that `tag` does not live long enough. I understand that it goes out of scope, but how to fix it?

```
use version_compare::Version;

fn main() {
  let tags: Vec<String> = vec!["1.2.1".to_string(),"1.2.2".to_string()];
  let mut max_ver = Version::from("0.0.0").unwrap();

  for tag in tags {
    let v_tag = Version::from(&tag.as_str()).unwrap();
    if v_tag > max_ver {
       max_ver = v_tag;
       }
    }
  println!("max_ver: {max_ver}");
}
```

Error:

```
Compiling rust-test2 v0.1.0 (/Users/scenox/rust-test2)
error[E0597]: `tag` does not live long enough
--> src/main.rs:8:36
    |
8   |         let v_tag = Version::from(&tag.as_str()).unwrap();
    |                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
9   |         if v_tag > max_ver {
    |                    ------- borrow later used here
...
 12 |         }
    |         - `tag` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the `for` loop *consumes* `tags`, meaning that each `String` is assigned to `tag` one-by-one, and at the end of each iteration that `String` is dropped.  At the end of the loop, the `Vec` itself is dropped.  However, `v_tag` might reference one of these `String` values, which means you could have a `Version` that borrows from a `String` that no longer exists.  This is a "use after free" bug that Rust has discovered in your code.

To fix this, iterate over `tags` without consuming it.  You can do this by iterating over a reference to the `Vec`:

```
for tag in &tags {
```

Or by using the `iter()` method:

```
for tag in tags.iter() {
```

In both of these cases, `tag` has type `&String`.  In your code, `tag` has type `String`.  This is an important distinction!